# Carrot2.Net NuGet 3.11 and 3.15 and IKVM

Tags: carrot2

Version 3.11 & 3.15 NuGet Packages requires IKVM.8.1.5717.0 yet is appears both are compiled against Version=7.2.4630.5 when looked at with ILSpy.

Running C# Examples show it will only work against IKVM.OpenJDK.Core, Version=7.2.4630.5.

I have a requirement of IKVM.8.1.5717.0 as I have other packages running in a WebSite which becomes problematic. We don't really want to change architecture to accommodate both 7.2 & 8.1.

Re-compiling the Org.Carrot2.Core.dll with IKVM.8.1.5717.0 from source and reproducing the Org.Carrot2.Core.NET.dll throws a

> Binary format of the specified custom attribute was invalid.

in the `org.carrot2.controller.process(Map attributes, params Class[] processingComponentClasses)`

Is there a downloadable stable version of 3.11 or 3.15 with IKVM.8.1.5717.0 somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is no: we don't have a binary build against IKVM 8 because it didn't pass our internal tests. IKVM's development has been ceased and we don't plan to upgrade to IKVM 8 at this moment (note that there are no stable versions of IKVM 8 [1]).

[1] https://sourceforge.net/projects/ikvm/files/ikvm/